# poly opencv semi-transperent

Tags: opencv, line, contour, polyfills

My question is for Opencv experts, I've detected road lines (left and right lines) so I was aiming to paint the road area with semi-transparent blue. So I used :

```
cv::fillPoly(image, ppt, npt, 1, CV_RGB(0, 0,200), lineType);
```

ppt- contain the points for right and left, 
npt- number of points

But, what I got it filled area over the road which is not my aim.

So, my question is there any solution to paint the road area with semi-transparent? I was told to add another channel like:

```
cv::Mat channel[3];
split(image, channel); 
    channel[0] = cv::Mat::zeros(image.rows, image.cols, CV_8UC1);
     merge(channel, 3, image);cv::imshow("kkk",image);
```

But the thing is I got all the image in semi-transparent and I want only the road area. Any ideas appreciated!!

thanks

Comment: paint the poly to a separate image with black background. then for each pixel: if polyimage-pixel isnt black: image-pixel = 0.5*imagepixel + 0.5*polyimage-pixel. instead of 0.5 you can use any transparancy factor x and (1-x)

Comment: Hi Micka, thanks a lot for the valuable reply. where can i use the image-pixel? is there any function to output image-pixel? i appreciate if you can give some code segment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code (couldnt test it on the mobile):

```
cv::Mat polyImage = cv::Mat(image.rows, image.cols, CV_8UC3,cv::Scalar (0,0,0));
cv::fillPoly(polyImage, ppt, npt, 1, CV_RGB(0, 0,200), lineType);

float transFactor = 0.5f; // the bigger the more transparent

for(int y=0;y <image.rows;++y)
    for(int x=0;x <image.cols; ++x)
    {
        if(polyImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x) != cv::Vec3b(0,0,0) )
            image.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x) = (transFactor)*image.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x) + (1.0f - transFactor)*polyImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x);
    }
```

Comment: thanks Micka for the reply, it was really helpful. I just have one question . First i got an error in this line : image.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x) = transFactorimage.at<cv::Vec3b> + (1.0f - transFactor)*polyImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x); it says that : error C3867 : 'cv::Mat::at' : function call missing argument list; use '&cv::Mat::at' to create a pointer to member-- so when i tried to edit :image.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x) = transFactorimage.at<cv::Vec3b> + (1.0f - transFactor)*polyImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x); ///it works but in the opposite way, the image is dark and the detected area is the real image,thanks alot

Comment: yes sorry, there was a semantic error. Try again! I changed from == to !=